# Чем чревато закрытие программы через taskkill?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Я хочу отловить момент, когда приложение пытаются закрыть и убить процесс своей же программы через *taskkill*. Сделать я это хочу, потому что при закрытии программы у меня вылетает какой-то `exception`, а мне надо её сдать завтра. Я конечно же разберусь из-за чего эти ошибки, но сейчас мне интересно, что может пойти не так, если я буду убивать сразу процесс программы?

Comment: так как неизвестно, что делает программа, то и неизвестно, что произойдет. Но скорее все будет более-менее ок.

Comment: @KoVadim Есть активное подключение к COM порту (чтение) и могут быть активные соединения через CoInitializeEx

Comment: тогда я не берусь предсказать, что будет. Может устройство, подключенное по COM будет в несогласованном состоянии (да, я вижу чтение, но все же). Также, так как есть COM (уже не порт), то может быть так, что следующий запуск программы  не сможет к нему подключится.